# Trigger Azure Function creating MS Graph Teams beta from Power Automate

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I have an Azure Function, that creates a new Teams team based on query variables. When I curl or Invoke-RestMethod  the function from the commandline, it executes and creates the team. When I run the function from a Power Automate flow, the function fails.

The Error message I get, when running from Flow indicates, that the call to the MS Graph Teams beta API is causing the issue according to this:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.NewTeam
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
Exception: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: {
  "error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: NotFound, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\nx-operationid: 14c6acc3601661469f152ac3d1d46b8a\r\nx-telemetryid: |14c6acc3601661469f152ac3d1d46b8a.7a1c5868_1.\r\nX-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 6259AF5FA1174BBCA9C2A70A448D15F4 Ref B: DB3EDGE1222 Ref C: 2020-04-01T05:38:26Z\r\nDate: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 05:38:26 GMT\r\n, ErrorMessage : {\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Failed to execute request for MiddleTier CreateTeamS2SAsync. Status code: NotFound.\"}],\"operationId\":\"14c6acc3601661469f152ac3d1d46b8a\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "37cb7b1c-ae0f-4191-8878-5a6d91578dd8",
      "date": "2020-04-01T05:38:26"
    }
  }
}
```

I have to generate a token before the team creation call and that executes just fine.

I have fixed CORS to allow the call cross-domain. Other calls from FLOW work as expected. It is only the last line in this code fails and only when called from Flow:

```
            $params = @{
                Header        = Get-AzureMSGraphHeader @credential #calls the Graph endpoint and generates a token
                Method        = 'Post'
                Uri           = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams'
            }
            $params.Body = @{
                displayName           = $TeamName
                description           = $TeamName
                "template@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')"
                'owners@odata.bind'   = $Owners
                visibility            = 'Private'
            } | convertto-json
            Write-Information "Executing command"
            Invoke-AzureMSGraph @params #calls the graph endpoint with the body and header above
```

Invoke-AzureMSGraph is a wrapper for Invoke-RestMethod. It sets ContentType to 'application/json'

Any pointers at where to look for a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any log from your function app? The current error is not very helpful here.

Comment: Hi Jack. That was, unfortunately, the only real error. However, when I tried to re-generate the error today, the error was gone. No code was changed, but the entire application has been redeployed to a different region due to CRM placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue disappeared when the exact same code was deployed on a newly created Azure function (in a different region). All code is the same.

It is in situations like that, deploy able templates come in handy.